# Requests - get content-type/size without fetching the whole page/content

Tags: python, http-headers, content-type, python-requests

I have a simple website crawler, it works fine, but sometime it stuck because of large content such as ISO images, .exe files and other large stuff. Guessing content-type using file extension is probably not the best idea.

**Is it possible to get content-type and content length/size without fetching the whole content/page?**

Here is my code:

```
requests.adapters.DEFAULT_RETRIES = 2
url = url.decode('utf8', 'ignore')
urlData = urlparse.urlparse(url)
urlDomain = urlData.netloc
session = requests.Session()
customHeaders = {}
if maxRedirects == None:
    session.max_redirects = self.maxRedirects
else:
    session.max_redirects = maxRedirects
self.currentUserAgent = self.userAgents[random.randrange(len(self.userAgents))]
customHeaders['User-agent'] = self.currentUserAgent
try:
    response = session.get(url, timeout=self.pageOpenTimeout, headers=customHeaders)
    currentUrl = response.url
    currentUrlData = urlparse.urlparse(currentUrl)
    currentUrlDomain = currentUrlData.netloc
    domainWWW = 'www.' + str(urlDomain)
    headers = response.headers
    contentType = str(headers['content-type'])
except:
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, filename=self.exceptionsFile)
    logging.exception("Get page exception:")
    response = None
```

Comment: Isn't it stored in the variable `contentType`?

Comment: Yes, it stored in contentType but the content already fetched.

Comment: ah i get what you meant. Check out my answer.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

**Yes.**

You can use the `Session.head` method to create `HEAD` requests:

```
response = session.head(url, timeout=self.pageOpenTimeout, headers=customHeaders)
contentType = response.headers['content-type']
```

A `HEAD` request similar to `GET` request, except that the message body would not be sent.

Here is a quote from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods):

> HEAD
>   Asks for the response identical to the one that would correspond to a GET request, but without the response body. This is useful for retrieving meta-information written in response headers, without having to transport the entire content.

Comment: Since the OP also asked about this: The size of the resource (in bytes) can be accessed with `response.headers['content-length']`.

Answer (score 10):

Use `requests.head()` for this. It will not return the message body. You should use `head` method if you are interested only in the `headers`. Check [this link](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.4) for detail.

```
h = requests.head(some_link)
header = h.headers
content_type = header.get('content-type')
```

Answer (score 6):

Sorry, my mistake, I should read documentation better. Here is the answer:
http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#advanced (Body Content Workflow)

```
tarball_url = 'https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/tarball/master'
r = requests.get(tarball_url, stream=True)
if int(r.headers['content-length']) > TOO_LONG:
  r.connection.close()
  # log request too long
```

Comment: Wouldn't that fetch the body as well? Just try getting `r.text`.

Comment: @aIKid by using `stream=True` it wouldn't actually fetch the body just yet. The headers would be received and requests would stop before reading the body. Closing the connection should prevent you from loading the body at all. That said, this should be the fallback option from using HEAD since not all servers properly respond to HEAD requests.

Comment: +1. The `stream=True` setting with `.get()` is better than `.head()`. Some servers may reject a `HEAD` request and return a 405 error. `amazon.com` is an example that behaves this way.

Answer (score 4):

Because `requests.head()` does **NOT** auto redirect, so a URL is redirected, `requests.head()` will get 0 for **Content-Length**.  So make sure `allow_redirects=True` is added.

```
r = requests.head(url, allow_redirects=True)
length = r.headers['Content-Length']
```

Refer to [Requests Redirection And History](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#redirection-and-history)