# How to Check Website Content type in python

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler

How to Check Website Content type in python

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

headers = { 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0',
            'Content-Type': '???',
            'Referer': 'https://www.manta.com/mb_43_A0_02/advertising_and_marketing/alaska?fbclid=IwAR3gfnW_bma08cITjmctgdcS5hLRau0vwl6WJHXdbwL9U3FkxIgrLkOG5rs',
            'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'}
```

How to find content type in python I want to **scrape** this website:

https://www.manta.com/mb_43_A0_02/advertising_and_marketing/alaska?fbclid=IwAR3gfnW_bma08cITjmctgdcS5hLRau0vwl6WJHXdbwL9U3FkxIgrLkOG5rs

Comment: which http client library are you using?

Comment: @CoreyGoldberg Question Updated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Requests - get content-type/size without fetching the whole page/content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23718424/requests-get-content-type-size-without-fetching-the-whole-page-content)

Comment: `Content-Type` describes what kind of data you are sending or you are receiving. https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type

If you're just requesting data (GET), then the server will tell you what `Content-Type` is. You don't tell it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you don't specify that header, requests library will default to sending:

> 'content-type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'

... which should be fine for making an HTTP GET request to the URL specified.